# How to return pointer using conditional statement?

Tags: c++, pointers, conditional-statements

The following code outputs the second number as the maximum.
If you need any other information please let me know.

```
#include <iostream>                                                     
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min);

double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min)
{
    return ((double *)((&Max > &Min) ? Max : Min));
}

int main(void)
{
    double *max;
    double Initial, Secondary;


    cout << "Enter the number followed by space then another number: ";
    cin >> Initial;
    cout << "\nIn-" << Initial;
    cin >> Secondary;
    cout << "\nSe-" << Secondary;
    //cout >> "Of " >> Inital >> "and " >> Secondary;
    //cout >> "the maximum is " >>
    max = ComputeMaximum((double*)&Initial,(double*)&Secondary);
    cout << "\nmax" << *max;
    return 0;
}
```

The next code outputs the first number as the maximum

```
#include <iostream>                                                     
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min);

double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min)
{
    return ((double *)((Max > Min) ? Max : Min));  // Here is the difference(& missing)
}

int main(void)
{
    double *max;
    double Initial, Secondary;


    cout << "Enter the number followed by space then another number: ";
    cin >> Initial;
    cout << "\nIn-" << Initial;
    cin >> Secondary;
    cout << "\nSe-" << Secondary;
    //cout >> "Of " >> Inital >> "and " >> Secondary;
    //cout >> "the maximum is " >>
    max = ComputeMaximum((double*)&Initial,(double*)&Secondary);
    cout << "\nmax" << *max;
    return 0;
}
```

What is being done wrong? I only need the maximum, not the second or first input.
I got the answer. Thank YOu all.

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>                                                     
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;
double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min);

double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min)
{
    return (double*)((*Max > *Min) ? Max : Min);
}

int main(void)
{
    double *max;
    double Initial, Secondary;


    cout << "Enter the number followed by space then another number: ";
    cin >> Initial;
    cout << "\nIn-" << Initial;
    cin >> Secondary;
    cout << "\nSe-" << Secondary;
    //cout >> "Of " >> Inital >> "and " >> Secondary;
    //cout >> "the maximum is " >>
    max = ComputeMaximum(&Initial, &Secondary);
    cout << "\nmax" << *max;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Based on your ComputeMaximum declaration, you don't need to write ComputeMaximum((double*)&Initial,(double*)&Secondary). Instead you can simply write: ComputeMaximum(&Initial, &Secondary).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min)
{
    return *Max > *Min ? Max : Min;
}
```

Note that I used `*Max` and `*Min` instead of `&Max` and `&Min`, i.e. dereferencing, not taking the address! Also note that you have a lot of unnecessary casts to `double*` for expressions that are already of the desired type. One exaple is your ComputeMaximum function body. Another example

```
max = ComputeMaximum((double*)&Initial,(double*)&Secondary);
```

Because `Initial` and `Secondary` are of type `double`, `&Initial` and `&Secondary` are of type `double*` so there is absolutely no need for the ugly unnecessary cast. Just use

```
max = ComputeMaximum(&Initial,&Secondary);
```

Similarly in other places.

I strongly recommend you to read [a good book on C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: What are some good C++ and C books? NVM just noticed the link

Comment: @user1781382: I specifically posted a link :) I, for one, recommend S.Lippmann's C++ Primer, 4th or higher editions

Comment: @user1781382: Also note that there is no book that is both good for C and C++. These are different languages with different paradigms, approaches, techniques, and philosophy. So first choose a language then learn it, without mixing the two

Comment: I have to learn both for class, but I know the books I have aren't too helpful.

Comment: @user1781382: If your class is called C/C++, then it's horrible, because it's like having a language class called Spanish/Italian. You can't find a book on Spanish/Italian.

Comment: And that is partially why I am here. I can handle java most of the time but this is just something else.

Answer (score 6):

You're comparing addresses. The correct way would be:

```
double *ComputeMaximum(const double *Max, const double *Min)
{
    return *Max > *Min ? Max : Min;
}
```

Your versions:

```
(Max > Min)
```

compares the pointers themselves, and

```
(&Max > &Min)
```

compares the addresses of the pointers, which is, again, wrong.

Also, you don't need pointers, and note that you have `std::max` which you can use.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using pointer in the first place? It is not even needed.

The following is a better implementation:

```
double ComputeMaximum(double a, double b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

Or if you wish to do something like this:

```
ComputeMaximum(x,y) = 100; //modify the one which is maximum
```

then reference is what you need:

```
double & ComputeMaximum(double & a, double & b)
{
    return a > b ? a : b;
}
```

By the way, you may would like to see [`std::max`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) (and [`std::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min)) from the Standard library.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of them returns the actual maximum.

You are passing pointers to doubles.  So the value of the variables **Min,Max** are an address that points to a double.

`&Max > &Min` ... This will compare the addresses of the variables **Max,Min** which are local to the function.

`Max > Min` ... This will compare the addresses that Min and Max point to (just address numbers).

`*Max > *Min` ... This will dereference the pointers, and compare the object they are pointing at. This is what you want to do...

```
return ((double *)((*Max > *Min) ? Max : Min));
```

Comment: Why do you need explicit double cast in front of ternary expression?

Comment: you don't really, both return values are of the same type, and they will be inferred correctly by the compiler.  just copy-pasting from the original...